python regex to match multiple words in a line without going to the next line
I'm writing a parser to parse the below output:
    admin@str-s6000-on-5:~$ show interface status Ethernet4
      Interface        Lanes    Speed    MTU         Alias    Vlan    Oper    Admin            Type    Asym PFC
---------------  -----------  -------  -----  ------------  ------  ------  -------  --------------  ----------
      Ethernet4  29,30,31,32      40G   9100  fortyGigE0/4   trunk      up       up  QSFP+ or later         off
PortChannel0001          N/A      40G   9100           N/A  routed      up       up             N/A         N/A
PortChannel0002          N/A      40G   9100           N/A  routed      up       up             N/A         N/A
PortChannel0003          N/A      40G   9100           N/A  routed      up       up             N/A         N/A
PortChannel0004          N/A      40G   9100           N/A  routed      up       up             N/A         N/A

I have made an attempt to write a regex to match all the fields as below
(\S+)\s+([\d,]+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+([up|down])+\s+([up|down]+)\s+([\w\s+?]+)\s+(\S+)

I'm able to get upto Admin column correctly. The column Type contains multiple words so i have used the pattern ([\w\s+?]+) hoping it will match multiple workds seperated by one space with + being optional followed by (\S+) to match the last column. The problem that I face is, regex ([\w\s+?]+) spawns over multiple lines and it gives me an output as below
Ethernet4  29,30,31,32      40G   9100  fortyGigE0/4   trunk      up       up  QSFP+ or later         off PortChannel0001          N/A 
I see that \s matches the new line as well. how to restrict that not to match the new line? could someone pls help me to clarify.
I looked at this space Regex for one or more words separated by spaces but that is not helping me either. can someone help me to understand this better?

Perhaps like this ^[^\S\n]*(\S+)[^\S\n]{2,}([\d,]+)[^\S\n]{2,}(\S+)[^\S\n]{2,}(\d+)[^\S\n]{2,}(\S+)[^\S\n]{2,}(\S+)[^\S\n]{2,}(up|down)+[^\S\n]{2,}(up|down)+[^\S\n]{2,}([\w +?]+)[^\S\n]{2,}(\S+) See https://regex101.com/r/2NqUGX/1

Suppose, for simplicity, the data were as follows.
str = """
admin@str-s6000-on-5:~$ show interface status Ethernet4
      Interface     Lanes   MTU  Alias    Ad         Type    Asym PFC
---------------  --------  ---- ------  ----  -----------  ----------
      Ethernet4  29,30,31  9100  fG0/4    up  Q+ or later         off
PortChannel0001       N/A  9100    N/A    up          N/A         N/A
"""

I would suggest you use both verbose (a.k.a. free spacing) mode (re.VERBOSE) and named capture groups to make the regular expression self-documenting:
import re

rgx = r"""
    ^                        # match beginning of line
    [ ]*                     # match zero or more spaces  
    (?P<Interface>\S+)       # match one or more non-whitespaces and
                             # save to capture group 'Interface'
    [ ]+
    (?P<Lanes>\d+(?:,\d+)*)  # match one or more strings of two or
                             # more digits separated by a comma and
                             # save to capture group 'Lanes'
    [ ]+
    (?P<MTU>\d+)             # match one or more digits and save to
                             # capture group 'MTU'
    [ ]+
    (?P<Alias>\S+)           # match one or more non-whitespaces and
                             # save to capture group 'Alias'
    [ ]+
    (?P<Ad>up|down)          # match 'up' or 'down' and save to
                             # capture group 'Ad'
    [ ]+
    (?P<Type>\S+(?:[ ]\S+)*) # match one or more groups of
                             # non-whitespaces separated by one
                             # space and save to capture group 'Type'
    [ ]*
    (?P<Asym_PFC>off|on)     # match 'up' or 'down' and save to
                             # capture group 'Asym_PFC'
    [ ]*
    $                        # match end of line
    """

Note I have assumed the whitespaces in the text are simply spaces (and not tabs, for one), in which case it is preferable to use spaces in the expression. Also, I've written each space to be in a capture group ([ ]); else it would be stripped out along with spaces that are not part of the expression. There are other ways to protect spaces, one being to escape them (\ ).
You may then extract the contents of the capture groups as follows.
match = re.search(rgx, str, re.VERBOSE | re.MULTILINE)

if match:
    print("capture group 'Interface': ", match.group('Interface'))
    print("capture group 'Lanes':     ", match.group('Lanes'))
    print("capture group 'MTU':       ", match.group('MTU'))
    print("capture group 'Alias':     ", match.group('Alias'))
    print("capture group 'Ad':        ", match.group('Ad'))
    print("capture group 'Type':      ", match.group('Type'))
    print("capture group 'Asym_PFC':  ", match.group('Asym_PFC'))
else:
    print('did not find')

which displays
capture group 'Interface':  Ethernet4
capture group 'Lanes':      29,30,31
capture group 'MTU':        9100
capture group 'Alias':      fG0/4
capture group 'Ad':         up
capture group 'Type':       Q+ or later
capture group 'Asym_PFC':   off

Demo
Note that it may be sufficient to determine if each line is a keeper, and if it is simply split the line on the regular expression  {2,}; that is, split on two or more spaces (after stripping off spaces at the beginning and/or end of the string). If, for example, lines of interest begin 'Ethernet', possibly padded left with spaces, we could use the regular expression r'^ *Ethernet.*' to identify lines of interest and r' {2,}' to split those lines and assign the pieces to variables.
Demo

I'm a newbie to Python, if it shows.

Thanks a lot @cary Swoveland for the wonderful explanation and readable syntax. I was not aware that we could write regex so cleanly like this. Thanks again.

As \s can also match newlines, you can use a negated character class [^\S\n] to match whitespace chars without newlines.
It appears that your data is separated by 2 or more spaces so you can use [^\S\n]{2,}
The second to last group can be non greedy ([\w +?]+?) but as there is also a space there, you could also match at least one word character (\w[\w +?]*?)
Note that ([up|down]) is a character class matching one of the listed characters and is not the same as (up|down) which is a group matching one of the alternatives.
For example:
^[^\S\n]*(\S+)[^\S\n]{2,}([\d,]+)[^\S\n]{2,}(\S+)[^\S\n]{2,}(\d+)[^\S\n]{2,}(\S+)[^\S\n]{2,}(\S+)[^\S\n]{2,}(up|down)+[^\S\n]{2,}(up|down)+[^\S\n]{2,}(\w[\w +?]*?)[^\S\n]{2,}(\S+)$

See a regex demo
If the delimiting space can also be 1 instead of 2, you could also write the pattern like this example.

good use of [^\S\n] all over the regex

You can use a pattern such as:
^\s*(\S+)\s+([\d,]+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(up|down)\s+(up|down)\s+(.*?)\s+(\S+)\s*$



By using ^ and $ anchors you can limit your pattern.
(.*?) simply extracts your 9th column.


Example:
import re

s = "      Ethernet4  29,30,31,32      40G   9100  fortyGigE0/4   trunk      up       up  QSFP+ or later         off   "
p = r'^\s*(\S+)\s+([\d,]+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(up|down)\s+(up|down)\s+(.*?)\s+(\S+)\s*$'
print(re.findall(p, s))


Prints
[('Ethernet4', '29,30,31,32', '40G', '9100', 'fortyGigE0/4', 'trunk', 'up', 'up', 'QSFP+ or later', 'off')]


You can also add proper flags, as needed: (?im)^\s*(\S+)\s+([\d,]+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(up|down)\s+(up|down)\s+(.*?)\s+(\S+)\s*$

You can construct the regex programmatically (10 columns = repeat the same pattern 10 times):
import re

s = """\
      Interface        Lanes    Speed    MTU         Alias    Vlan    Oper    Admin            Type    Asym PFC
---------------  -----------  -------  -----  ------------  ------  ------  -------  --------------  ----------
      Ethernet4  29,30,31,32      40G   9100  fortyGigE0/4   trunk      up       up  QSFP+ or later         off
PortChannel0001          N/A      40G   9100           N/A  routed      up       up             N/A         N/A
PortChannel0002          N/A      40G   9100           N/A  routed      up       up             N/A         N/A
PortChannel0003          N/A      40G   9100           N/A  routed      up       up             N/A         N/A
PortChannel0004          N/A      40G   9100           N/A  routed      up       up             N/A         N/A
"""

print(*re.findall(r"\s*(\S+(?:\s\S+)*)" * 10 + "$", s, flags=re.M)[2:], sep="\n")

Prints:
('Ethernet4', '29,30,31,32', '40G', '9100', 'fortyGigE0/4', 'trunk', 'up', 'up', 'QSFP+ or later', 'off')
('PortChannel0001', 'N/A', '40G', '9100', 'N/A', 'routed', 'up', 'up', 'N/A', 'N/A')
('PortChannel0002', 'N/A', '40G', '9100', 'N/A', 'routed', 'up', 'up', 'N/A', 'N/A')
('PortChannel0003', 'N/A', '40G', '9100', 'N/A', 'routed', 'up', 'up', 'N/A', 'N/A')
('PortChannel0004', 'N/A', '40G', '9100', 'N/A', 'routed', 'up', 'up', 'N/A', 'N/A')


HI @Andrej, thanks for taking time to respond.. just trying to understand a bit. what does * do preceding the re.findall ? . Also if you could explain the purpose of "$" at the end? does it indicate the end of the line?

@Vijay string * 10 means: repeat this string 10 times. Yes, $ means end of line. That's why I have re.M flag set on.

No. no. i was trying to understand the * before re.findall
